# Using new script bin/crawl - skipping urls different batch id (null)

Tags: apache, solr, web-crawler, nutch

I want to crawl a lot of websites from my seed.txt with Nutch 2.1 new crawl script bin/crawl.

The problem is that everytime I run my script, it does not fetch or parse anything (no urls) with message "Skipoing [here is concrete url] different batch id (null)"

Here is some output from the log:

```
Start old crawling linked TV:
InjectorJob: starting
InjectorJob: urlDir: /opt/ir/nutch/urls
InjectorJob: finished
```

It looks like that the injection of urls was ok

```
Sun Jun 30 19:45:10 CEST 2013 : Iteration 1 of 2
Generating batchId
Generating a new fetchlist
GeneratorJob: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
GeneratorJob: starting
GeneratorJob: filtering: false
GeneratorJob: topN: 50000
GeneratorJob: done
GeneratorJob: generated batch id: 1372614310-1071860715
Fetching :
FetcherJob: starting
FetcherJob: batchId: 1372614310-24672
Fetcher: Your 'http.agent.name' value should be listed first in 'http.robots.agents' property.
FetcherJob: threads: 50
FetcherJob: parsing: false
FetcherJob: resuming: false
FetcherJob : timelimit set for : 1372614928303
Using queue mode : byHost
Fetcher: threads: 50
QueueFeeder finished: total 0 records. Hit by time limit :0
-finishing thread FetcherThread0, activeThreads=0
-finishing thread FetcherThread1, activeThreads=0
-finishing thread FetcherThread2, activeThreads=0
-finishing thread FetcherThread3, activeThreads=0
```

.... here is iteration to FetcherThread48 and it continues

```
Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1
-finishing thread FetcherThread49, activeThreads=0
Fetcher: throughput threshold sequence: 5
0/0 spinwaiting/active, 0 pages, 0 errors, 0.0 0.0 pages/s, 0 0 kb/s, 0 URLs in 0 queues
-activeThreads=0
FetcherJob: done
Parsing :
ParserJob: starting
ParserJob: resuming:    false
ParserJob: forced reparse:      false
ParserJob: batchId:     1372614310-24672
Skipping http://www.brugge.be/internet/en/musea/bruggemuseum/stadhuis/index.htm; different batch id (null)
Skipping http://www.galloromeinsmuseum.be/; different batch id (null)
Skipping http://www.museumdrguislain.be/; different batch id (null)
Skipping http://www.muzee.be/; different batch id (null)
Skipping http://musea.sint-niklaas.be/; different batch id (null)
```

...
...
and skipping more urls from my seed
...
...

```
ParserJob: success
CrawlDB update
DbUpdaterJob: starting
Limit reached, skipping further inlinks for de.ard.www:http/
Limit reached, skipping further inlinks for de.rbb-online.mediathek:http/
Limit reached, skipping further inlinks for de.rbb-online.www:http/
DbUpdaterJob: done
```

Do you know where is the probleam, please? I am absolutely exhausted of configuration of this tool and trying to work well with it...

Comment: Did you modify the Nutch regex-urlfilter.txt to accept the urls ?

Comment: There is a problem that no page is fetched so I can not parse anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solution is that I used older version of the nutch (2.1). After updating to 2.2.1 this problem dissapeared.